# Can we use WHILE to select more rows? -- make calculations on a table with dates between each day and the next one

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, union

I am a bit new to SQL Server and here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a table containing multiple rows of data and each row has a date entry (some rows have the same date).

I would like to create a procedure that takes two dates as parameters (let's say the 1st of June and the 30st of June) and calculate the difference between two columns for each period of two days found between both dates.  i.e. I would like to calculate the difference between the 30 and the 29, then the 29 and the 28, and so on.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consomVspPools (@start DATE, @end DATE)
                    AS
                    DECLARE @myStart DATE, @myEnd DATE
                    SET @myEnd = @end
                    SET @myStart = DATEADD(day, -1, @myEnd)
                    SELECT MAX(dateCollecte),
                    MAX(CASE WHEN dateCollecte = @myEnd THEN capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB ELSE 0 END) AS endUsedCapacityInKB,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN dateCollecte = @myStart THEN capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB ELSE 0 END) AS startUsedCapacityInKB
                    FROM Vsp_Pool
                    WHILE(@myStart >= @start)
                    BEGIN
                            UNION
                            SELECT MAX(dateCollecte),
                            MAX(CASE WHEN dateCollecte = @myEnd THEN capacityInKB ELSE 0 END) AS endCapacityInKB,
                            MAX(CASE WHEN dateCollecte = @myStart THEN capacityInKB ELSE 0 END) AS startCapacityInKB
                            FROM Vmware
                            SET @myEnd = myStart
                            SET @myStart = DATEADD(day, -1, @myEnd)
                    END
```

But it doesn't work.  There is a syntax error near the UNION.

Comment: You might consider using a temporary table to store the values from the loop and select as the results later on instead.

Comment: Please google "Sql Server RBAR" (row by agonizing row) and try to avoid a bad habit early...

Comment: This looks like a good time to use a tally table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table to itself using a join like this

```
select
   theDay.dateCollecte,
   theDay.capacityInKB - theDayBefore.capacityInKB as difference,
from 
  vs_pool as theDay -- join the table
iner join
  vs_pools as theDayBefor -- with itself
-- when the first row has 1 day of difference with the second one
on theDay.dateCollecte = DATEADD(day, 1, theDayBefore.dateCollecte)
```

Note that join a row of the table with another row of the table which is of the previous day, so now you have available the information of both days to make the required calculations.

I don't know the exact structure of your table, but this is the basi idea to achieve what you need.

If there are more than one row per day, you simply have to change the `vs_pool as theDay` and the `vs_pool as theDayBefore` for a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) that normalizes the date as desired. a CTE lets you define a sort of "temporal view" which you can use in the following query:

```
WITH ShapedData as (/* your select here */)
Select ... from ShapedData
```

I.e. you can define something that would take the role of `vs_pool`in my previous example, that contains the aggregated data, and query it directly using exactly the same technique.

*NOTE: even if you can implement it like that, using a cursor (loop) is not the ideal way of querying relational databases. It's much better to use a set-based approach, as shown here. The performance is much better, and you'll really notice it if the set of data is big.*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put WHILE there. That is not a correct syntax for a SELECT statement.
Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) for SELECT syntax.

Comment: do you need to query from two tables - Vsp_Pool and Vmware?
and selections vary when you select the end and used capacity for Vsp_Pool and Vmware?